# Type has no subscript members, for word scrambler app

Tags: arrays, uikit, func

I am making a word scrambler app, and I have some issues in the code.

I have an array of instances of a struct, and I am randomly choosing 5 out of the array and appending them to an array named: `chosen5`.

I made a function to show the contents of the first word in the array `chosen5`, but I have an error saying:

> Type 'ViewController.word' has no subscript members

[image]

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: Hi Antony, to enable people to test your code it is a better practice to post your code rather than a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 0):

We need to know the properties of the `struct ViewController.word` to give you a decent answer.

But from what I can understand, if you have an array of structs, you should simply access it using `chosen5[0]`, which should return the first element of this array.